# KCFinder - cannot write to upload folder. /upload

Tags: ckeditor, kcfinder

I am just trying to use KCFinder with CKEditor for uploads and browser. But when I try to upload something, it sends me the following message

> KCFinder - cannot write to upload folder. /upload

Path for upload files is **domain/upload/**
and of KCFinder is **domain/admin/kcfinder/**

Here is a part from my **config.php**:

```
   'disabled' => false,
   'uploadURL' => "/upload/",
   'uploadDir' => "/upload/",
   'theme' => "default"
```

Comment: I have corrected the formatting for the error message to highlight it. I have also removed the *help please* and *thanks* notes because they are considered as fluff and are not required.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271925/kcfinder-upload-image-issue/43618477#43618477