# Kcfinder Upload image issue

Tags: image, codeigniter, ckeditor, kcfinder

My site is a Codeigniter with kcfinder and ckeditor, and my issue is when I try upload and load an image, this image upload correctly in an autocreated folder */assets/kcfinder/.thumbs/images/*, but When I select the image from server, the URL is wrong and I can not see it. How can I set the correct path?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: how do you pick the image from server? I suggest you edit your question!

Comment: Hi Vickel, I select the image from server clicking in button "Show server". Image is there but I select it, it does not load correctly. Image not show, I think is a path problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
In ../assets/kcfinder/config.php I changed:

'uploadURL' from "upload" to Absolute url and in
'uploadDir' from "" to "upload" and it worked!

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I thing that the problem is that you need to add the base url in your image path

base_url() . 'images/' . $img;

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below code to set your KcFinder config settings:

```
<?php
/**
 * KcFinder has a SESSION key name 'KCFINDER'
 * You can use this as setup your dynamic config vales
 * if you set uploadURL and uploadDir via SESSION, KcFinder ignore config.php
 * to get these values and it start using SESSION values
 */
$_SESSION['KCFINDER'] = array(
    'disabled'  => false,
    'uploadURL' => 'http://www.example.com/upload',
    'uploadDir' => 'var/htdocs/www/upload'
);
```

More: **[See Link](https://github.com/neerajsinghsonu/KcFinder_CkEditor_Absolute_Url)**